# DNN 8 (DotNetNuke) How to configure SignalR?

Tags: signalr, dotnetnuke

For one of my projects I have to use DNN. 
I created a regular ASP.NET project in which I experimented with SignalR and it works perfect.

But within DNN version 8, after installing the SignalR NuGet packages both Core and for JS and creating the startup class such as this:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

A testhub class such as this:

```
public class MyTestHub : Hub
    {
        public void Hello(string message)
        {
            //Clients.All.hello();

            // set all clients
            var clients = Clients.All;

            // call javascript function
            clients.test("This is a test");

            Trace.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

and finally an index page:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        DNN 8 SignalR TestPage
    </div>
</body>
</html>


    <script src="~/DesktopModules/MVC/AC_ChatTest1/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script>

        $(function () {

            console.log('in on ready');

            // set up the hub connection
            var hub = $.connection.mytest;

            console.log(hub);

            // define JS function that is called from
            hub.client.test = function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }

            $.connection.hub
                .start()
                .done(function () {
                    hub.server.hello("SignalR is working.");
                })

        });

    </script>
```

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, these are the steps needed to make signalR work in DNN 7.1+:

1. Install NuGet Packages.
2. Create a startup class like this:

> ```
> [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
>     namespace MyNamespace.MyModuleName
>     {
>         public class Startup
>         {
>             public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>             {
>                 app.MapSignalR();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

3. To eliminate the error localhost/signalr/hubs (404 not found) Need to modify dbo.hostsettings table in DNN so run this query:

> ```
> IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.hostsettings WHERE SettingName = 
> 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx' )
>
>   insert into dbo.hostsettings
>     (SettingName
>     , SettingValue
>     , SettingIsSecure 
>     , CreatedByUserId
>     , CreatedOnDate
>     , LastModifiedByUserId
>     , LastModifiedOnDate
>     )
>     values(
>     'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'
>     ,'/DesktopModules/|/Providers|/LinkClick\.aspx|/SignalR'
>     , 0
>     , -1
>     , GETDATE()
>     , -1
>     , GETDATE()
>     )
>
> GO
>
> IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.hostsettings WHERE SettingName = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx' 
> and SettingValue not like '%/signalr%' )
>
> update dbo.hostsettings
>     set settingValue = (select settingValue + '|/signalr' from dbo.hostsettings where 
>  settingname = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx')
> where settingname = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'
>
> GO
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in the context of a DNN module?

If so, you should take a look at this: https://www.chrishammond.com/Blog/itemid/2624/using-signalr-with-dotnetnuke-modules.  Chris' module is available on GitHub, too.

If not, you should switch to a module and take a serious approach with Chris' solution.

Comment: yes im using it in the context of a DNN module. The difference from that tutorial is that the RouteMapper class is not used anymore starting with SignalR version 2+. Instead an Owin Startup class is used the mapping to signalR is done like this:  app.MapSignalR(). The problem was  that there was a db modification that needed to be made as well, I posted the answer.

Comment: Might check out https://github.com/chrishammond/dnnchat that's the last thing I've touched regarding SignalR and DNN. Still works at www.dnnchat.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
            // set up the hub connection
        var hub = $.connection.mytest;
```

Should be:

```
            // set up the hub connection
        var hub = $.connection.myTestHub;
```

Comment: thanks but same result, the issue has to do with DNN I think. There's some things that are different when configuring DNN than a regular asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Sorry cannot help with DNN. Just noticed the connection was trying to connect to a hub that was not named the same.